# Open source software for calculation of eigenvalues of symbolic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symbolic-computation

I have following matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
-\alpha & 0 & \beta & \gamma\cdot\omega_m \\
0 & -\alpha & -\gamma\cdot\omega_m & \beta \\
R_r\frac{L_h}{L_r} & 0 & -\frac{R_r}{L_r} & -\omega_m \\
0 & R_r\frac{L_h}{L_r} & \omega_m & -\frac{R_r}{L_r} 
\end{bmatrix}

where

$$ \alpha = \frac{R_s + R_r\frac{L^2_h}{L^2_r}}{L_{s\sigma}+\frac{L_h}{L_r}L_{r\sigma}} $$
$$ \beta = \frac{R_r\frac{L_h}{L^2_r}}{L_{s\sigma}+\frac{L_h}{L_r}L_{r\sigma}} $$
$$ \gamma = \frac{\frac{L_h}{L_r}}{L_{s\sigma}+\frac{L_h}{L_r}L_{r\sigma}}\cdot p_p $$

and I would like to calculate the eigenvalues of that in symbolic manner.

EDIT:

The matrix can be rewritten in following form

\begin{bmatrix}
-a & 0 & b & c\cdot d \\
0 & -a & -c\cdot d & b \\
e\cdot f & 0 & -e & -d \\
0 & e\cdot f & d & -e 
\end{bmatrix}

I have been looking for some open source software usable for that purpose. I have already tried the wxMaxima but I have received some overcomplicated expressions containing the square roots which I am not able to simplify. Can anybody recommend me any open source software which offers good results for eigenvalues calculation in symbolic manner?

Comment: (Almost) every CAS can do a symbolic computation. It is no surprise that the solution is complicated. Why do you expect an "easy" formula? Perhaps you can give an explicit example in variables $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ etc. only. The other symbols are confusing. Then I can post my solution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you for your reaction. The matrix is system matrix of state space model of the three phase induction motor. The other symbols in $$\alpha, \beta, \gamma$$ are electrical parameters of the machine (such as resistances and inductances of its windings).

Comment: I have attempted to reformulate the matrix with the $a, b, c, d, e, f$ symbols.

Comment: Do you really need eigenvalues, or is is an intermediate step to obtain something else? If you explain your aim, maybe someone can suggest another path to the solution.

Comment: Why do you want a symbolic expression ?

Comment: @enzotib My target is to design Luenberger state observer for the three phase induction motor. To be able to do so I need to specify desired dynamics of the observer which should be faster than the dynamics of my system (induction motor). So I have been attempting to find the poles of it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My intention was to have symbolic expression of the poles of my system (induction motor) to observe influence of individual electrical parameters to the position of the poles.

Comment: @Steve: the expressions are so awful that I am afraid you will get no insight with them. Probably better to compute sensitivity coefficients numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that we can find a symbolic expression for the eigenvalues as follows:

The matrix can be written in the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{-a & b\\ ef & -e} \otimes I_2 + \pmatrix{0& -cd\\0 & d} \otimes \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0},
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes a Kronecker product. In other words: via the standard representation of the complex numbers over $\Bbb R^2$, this is the real analog to the complex matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{-a & b\\ef & -e} + i \pmatrix{0 & -cd\\0 & d} = 
\pmatrix{-a & b - icd\\ef & -e + id}.
$$
In other words, this matrix $M$ has the following property: for any real numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, we have
$$
M \pmatrix{x_1 + ix_2\\ x_3 + ix_4} = \pmatrix{y_1 + iy_2\\ y_3 + iy_4} \iff
A \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4} = \pmatrix{y_1\\ y_2\\y_3\\ y_4}.
$$
Consequently, the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $A$ can be found using the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $M$. If $\lambda = a + bi \in \Bbb C, x \in \Bbb R^4$ are such that
$$
M \pmatrix{x_1 + ix_2\\x_3 + ix_4} = \lambda \pmatrix{x_1 + ix_2\\ x_3 + ix_4},
$$
then it follows that $a \pm bi$ are eigenvalues of $A$, with
$$
A \pmatrix{x_1 + ix_2\\x_2 - ix_1\\ x_3 + ix_4\\ x_4 - ix_3 } = 
(a + bi)\pmatrix{x_1 + ix_2\\x_2 - ix_1\\ x_3 + ix_4\\ x_4 - ix_3 }, \quad
A \pmatrix{x_1 - ix_2\\x_2 + ix_1\\ x_3 - ix_4\\ x_4 + ix_3 } = 
(a - bi)\pmatrix{x_1 - ix_2\\x_2 + ix_1\\ x_3 - ix_4\\ x_4 + ix_3 }.
$$

The eigenvalues of this complex matrix will simply be the solutions to the characteristic equation
$$
\lambda^2 - k_1 \lambda + k_2 = 0,
$$
with $k_1 = \operatorname{tr}(M) = -a - e + id$ and $k_2 = \det(M) = -a(-e + id) - (b - i cd)f$. It follows that the eigenvalues of $M$ are given by
$$
\lambda_\pm =  \frac{k_1 \pm \sqrt{k^2 - 4k_2}}{2},
$$
where we note that this square root is the square root of a complex number.

From there, we deduce that the original matrix has eigenvalues
$$
\lambda_+, \bar \lambda_+, \lambda_-, \bar \lambda_-,
$$
where $\bar z$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$.

---

An equivalent approach: consider the similar matrix
$$
\frac 12 \pmatrix{-i  &  1\\ 1 & -i
\\ &&-i  &  1\\ &&1 & -i} 
\pmatrix{-a & 0 & b & c\cdot d \\
0 & -a & -c\cdot d & b \\
e\cdot f & 0 & -e & -d \\
0 & e\cdot f & d & -e }
\pmatrix{-i  &  1\\ 1 & -i
\\ &&-i  &  1\\ &&1 & -i} = \\
\pmatrix{-a & 0 & b - icd & 0\\
0 & -a & 0 & b + icd\\
ef & 0 & -e + id & 0\\
0 & ef & 0 & -e - id}.
$$
With the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $K_2$, we have
$$
K_2^T\pmatrix{-a & 0 & b - icd & 0\\
0 & -a & 0 & b + icd\\
ef & 0 & -e + id & 0\\
0 & ef & 0 & -e - id}K_2 = 
\pmatrix{-a & b - icd\\ef & -e + id\\
&&-a & b + icd\\&&ef & -e - id}
$$

Comment: I think it is $-a$

Comment: @enzotib Good catch; fixed it.

Comment: maybe also $-cd$?

Comment: @enzotib Thanks again... :)

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you for the interesting idea. I understand the very first expression for decomposition of the matrix $A$. I am sorry but I am not able to fully understand how I can exploit this decomposition for determining the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$. The $M$ matrix mentioned below the $A$ matrix decomposition seems to me totally unrelated to the $A$ matrix. May I ask you for clarification?

Comment: @Steve In a way, the "equivalent approach" at the end explains things, but I'll add an explanation in the beginning to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: @Steve I've added something. I think there's a nice formula for the eigenvectors of $A$ as well; should be adding that in a bit.

Comment: @Steve see my latest edit.

Answer (score 4):

We do have software for symbolic computations, but none for miracles.

The Eigenvalues of a $4\times4$ matrix are the roots of a quartic equation, which have a notoriously complex expression.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is given by
\begin{align}
\chi(t) &= t^4 + 2t^3(a + e) +t^2(a^2 + 4ae - 2bef + d^2 + e^2) + {}\\
 &\qquad+2t(a^2e - abef + ad^2 + ae^2 - be^2f - cd^2ef) +{}\\
&\qquad+ a^2d^2 + a^2e^2 - 2abe^2f - 2acd^2ef + b^2e^2f^2 + c^2d^2e^2f^2
\end{align}
The eigenvalues are the zeros of it over the given field. There are explicit formulas for the solutions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation). However, they are very complicated.

Comment: Per my answer, this polynomial can be factored as 
$$
\chi(t) = (\lambda^2 - k_1 \lambda + k_2)(\lambda^2 - \bar k_1 \lambda + \bar k_2),
$$
with $k_1 = -a - e + id$ and $k_2 = -a(-e + id) - (b + i cd)f$.

Comment: @Yves Sure, and every polynomial has roots. The goal of the asker, however, is to find an expression for these roots, and the factorization that I give accomplishes something equivalent. Note that the factorization I give is much "nicer" than the result one expects from naively solving for the roots of the quartic.

Comment: @Yves First of all, a quick correction: it is not true that every quartic polynomial factors into two quadratic, conjugate ones. For example, $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ does not. Second, yes, there certainly methods that do this factorization as a first step, but this factorization is not generally as easy to find as it happens to be in this particular case.

Comment: @Yves In particular, it is not generally true that finding the roots of a quartic with real coefficients can be reduced to the problem of finding the roots of a single quadratic with complex coefficients.

Comment: @Yves If I understand you correctly, your point seems to be "it was pointless to derive symbolic expressions for the eigenvalues because any software would produce the same result." Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: I am saying that there is little that you can gain.

Answer (score 0):

This response is (perhaps) barely appropriate as an answer rather than a comment.  However, it may well be the best that the OP can do.

First of all, consider trying to programmatically identify the general roots of a quartic equation.  Although the general formula is *somewhat* unwieldy, writing a computer program (e.g. using java, c, python, ...) to calculate the roots should be **very** straight forward.

Similarly, writing a computer program to calculate the eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix should also be straight forward.  Given the other responses to this posting, I would say (as a retired professional programmer) that the OP's surrendering to the need to write his own software may be best.

**Edit** 
It just occurred to me that dealing with roots like $(1 + \sqrt{2})$ or $[1 + \sin(23^{\circ})]$ may be problematic if the OP needs **exactness** rather than (for example) the right answers correct to 10 decimal places.

If **exactness** is needed, then the OP has to (somehow) anticipate all the various forms that the solution may come in and develop special methods to handle them.  For example, computing 
$(1 + \sqrt{2}) \times (3 - \sqrt{2}) \;=\; [1 + 2\sqrt{2}]$ would probably require special code.

Comment: Right, with an implementation of the complex numbers operations, programming the root formulas is easy. (Though dealing with the cases that are numerically unstable is probably arduous.) The characteristic polynomial of small matrices is readily obtained by the Faddeev–Le Verrier algorithm. But the OP is not after accurate results, but after a qualitative understanding of the influence of the parameters.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "But the OP is not after accurate results, but after a qualitative understanding of the influence of the parameters." Very interesting reply.