# Characteristic polynomial of matrix with complex numbers

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I have been attempting to determine characteristic polynomial of below given matrix

$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 & \frac{R_R}{L_M\cdot L_L}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2-\frac{1}{L_L}\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J} \\
R_R\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 & -\frac{R_R}{L_M}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2+\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J}
\end{bmatrix}
$

where

$
\mathbf{E}_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\mathbf{J} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

I have found following derivation

$$
\begin{align} 
\mathbf{A}-\lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_4
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 & \frac{R_R}{L_M\cdot L_L}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2-\frac{1}{L_L}\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J} \\
R_R\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 & -\frac{R_R}{L_M}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2+\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J}
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 & \mathbf{Z} \\
\mathbf{Z} & \lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2-\lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 & -\frac{1}{L_L}\left(-\frac{R_R}{L_M}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2+\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J}\right) \\
R_R\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 & \left(-\frac{R_R}{L_M}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2+\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J}-\lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_2\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

where

$
\mathbf{Z} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\mathbf{E}_4 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Then below given substitution has been used

$$
\delta=\frac{1}{L_L}
$$

$$
a=-\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2
$$

$$
b=-\frac{R_R}{L_M}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2+\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J}
$$

$$
c=R_R\cdot\mathbf{E}_2
$$

The substitution resulted in following matrix

$$
\begin{align} 
\mathbf{A}-\lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_4
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a-\lambda & -\delta\cdot b \\
c & b-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Based on last matrix following characteristic polynomial has been written

$$
\lambda^2-(a+b)\cdot\lambda+(a+\delta\cdot c)\cdot b
$$

I have doubts regarding the mathematical correctness of the above mentioned derivation. The problem which I have is related to the substitution in the elements $-\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2-\lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_2 = a-\lambda$ and $\left(-\frac{R_R}{L_M}\cdot\mathbf{E}_2+\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J}-\lambda\cdot\mathbf{E}_2\right) = b-\lambda$. Does anybody have any idea how to find the characteristic polynomial in mathematical correct way? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: The matrix $A$ is of dimension $4$ if I understand well. Hence its characteristic polynomial is of degree $4$. Computing it *by hand* won’t be a special fun...

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thank you for your reaction. Yes, you are correct. The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is $4\times 4$ matrix. What do you think about the mathematical correctness of the above mentioned derivation of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @Steve You can use the exact same trick that I describe in [my answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3779725/81360). That is, it suffices to calculate the eigenvalues of the complex matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L} & \frac{R_R}{L_M\cdot L_L}-i\frac{1}{L_L}\omega_m \\
R_R & -\frac{R_R}{L_M}+i\omega_m
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @Steve Your computation is also correct. It is justified in this case because the $2 \times 2$ block-entries commute

Comment: @BenGrossman thank you for your reaction. Does it mean that the substitution mentioned above is in your opinion correct?

Comment: @Steve Well, almost correct: $\lambda^2-(a+b)\cdot\lambda+(a+\delta\cdot c)\cdot b$ is a matrix, but the characteristic polynomial is a scalar-valued polynomial. Your characteristic polynomial should instead be
$$
\det(\lambda^2-(a+b)\cdot\lambda+(a+\delta\cdot c)\cdot b)
$$